# PHP пауза в foreach

Tags: php

Есть массив с моделями телефонов, вывожу все марки в таблицу через foreach.
Пытаюсь разделить модели по производителю через отдельный TR.

```
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<?php 
$arr = array('Samsung Galaxy S7', 'Samsung Galaxy S8', 'Samsung Galaxy S9', 
'Samsung Galaxy S10', 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 3', 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 4', 
'Xiaomi Redmi Note 5', 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 6'); 
?>
<table style="width:100%"> 
<tbody>

<?php 
    foreach($arr as $arr_line) {
        $modelarray = explode (' ', $arr_line);
        $curr_model = $modelarray[0];
?>  
<tr>
<?php 
    if ($curr_model == $modelarray[0]) {
        echo '<tr> <td>'.$modelarray[0].'</td> </tr>';
    }
?>
    <td><?php echo $arr_line; ?></td>
    <td>Some Info 2</td>
    <td>Some Info 3</td>
</tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Проблема в том, что при таком раскладе модель выводится над каждой записью

```
Samsung
Samsung Galaxy S7   Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Samsung
Samsung Galaxy S8   Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Samsung
Samsung Galaxy S9   Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Samsung
Samsung Galaxy S10
```

а хотелось бы чтобы было так

```
Samsung
Samsung Galaxy S7       Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Samsung Galaxy S8       Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Samsung Galaxy S9       Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Samsung Galaxy S10
Xiaomi
Xiaomi Redmi Note 3     Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Xiaomi Redmi Note 4     Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Xiaomi Redmi Note 5     Some Info 2     Some Info 3
Xiaomi Redmi Note 6     Some Info 2     Some Info 3
```

Каким образом делать паузу в foreach, и выводить производителя только когда изменилась переменная производителя?
Прошу строго не судить, только начинаю.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: тв почти все правильно делаешь, только сравнивать надо не на "равно", а "не равно". И присваивать новое значение не до условия, а после. А то сейчас у тебя $curr_model == $modelarray[0], поскольку ты сам строчкой выше приравнял их друг к другу

Comment: и сравнить  до вывода `<tr>` с данными